React Native - EMDK error: Could not find method compileOnly() for arguments [com.symbol:emdk:7.0.0.]
Does anyone here tried the React Native Zebra Scanner?
can someone please help me? How to install the emdk?
When I tried the package I got this error.
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.symbol:emdk:7.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/symbol/emdk/7.0.0/emdk-7.0.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/symbol/emdk/7.0.0/emdk-7.0.0.pom
       - file:/Users/usr/Desktop/barcodetest/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/symbol/emdk/7.0.0/emdk-7.0.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/symbol/emdk/7.0.0/emdk-7.0.0.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/symbol/emdk/7.0.0/emdk-7.0.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-zebra-scanner

This is my build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
        kotlinVersion = "1.9.22"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
    }
    dependencies {
      compileOnly('com.symbol:emdk:7.0.0')
  }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"

I also followed this solution but didn't work.
https://developer.zebra.com/forum/25271
